# Image Processing In Matlab : Image Compression Hadamard Transorm

Tags: image, matlab

Hi I want to implement a block based Hadamard transform for image compression with variable N:Number of Blocks and variable percent of elimination 
This in my code but it doesn't work properly:

```
img=imread('cameraman.tif');
N = input('Please Inter Size Of Block: ');
E = input('Please Inter Elimination of Coefficient Percentage:');
E=100-E;
E=round(100/E);
S=round(N/E);
m=log2(N);
I = im2double(img);
T = (1/(2^m))*hadamard(N);
wht = @(block_struct) T * block_struct.data * T';
B = blockproc(I,[N N],wht);
mask = [ones(S,S) , zeros(S,N-S); zeros((N-S),N)];
B2 = blockproc(B,[N N],@(block_struct) mask .* block_struct.data);
invwht = @(block_struct) T' * block_struct.data * T;
I2 = blockproc(B2,[N N],invwht);
imshow(I)
figure
imshow(I2)
```

Comment: Why does it not work properly?

Comment: tnx for your attention I handled it in another way! problem solved

Comment: You may want to write an answer that explains what you did